# How do you modify the WordPress directory structure?

Tags: customization, directory, deployment

I would like to use the following directory structure for WordPress.

```
├── composer.json
├── config
│   ├── application.php
│   └── environments
│       ├── development.php
│       ├── staging.php
│       └── production.php
├── vendor
└── web
    ├── app
    │   ├── plugins
    │   ├── themes
    │   └── uploads
    ├── wp-config.php
    ├── index.php
    └── wp
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your proposed structure, I am assuming that the only thing that would be changed is:

1. The WordPress files are all kept in a folder you've called web.
   For this just create a .htaccess file in root folder, and put this content inside (just change example.com):

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
   RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/index.php [L] 
   </IfModule>
   ```
2. Rename the `wp-content` folder (I do not suggest doing this, as some plugins or themes may not work simply because they are not written using best practices and hard coded the folder name). In your `wp-config.php` put this:

   ```
   define( "WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME", "app" );
   ```

Now, if I am assuming that EVERYTHING else WP is in the directory WP, then things would change slightly, but that should give you an idea of how.

You can read more by looking at the [WordPress support pages](https://wordpress.org/support/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#moving-specific-wordpress-folders).

Comment: I don’t know I’ve not tried, but I assume so.

Comment: Did this answer work for you @Anonymous?